WooCommerce Shortcode - space between price & add-to-cart
This shortcode nicely displays the price of a product and the add-to-cart button side by side:
[add_to_cart id="xx" style="" show_price="true" quantity="1"]
But they are bunched up next to each other. How do I add a space between these two things? I'm sure it's relatively easy, but nothing I try works (being a dabbler, not a coder). Btw, style="" gets rid of the default border around the edge which I didn't like.

Can you share the code related to the issue? The HTML/css code or at least the website to make tests.

Add the following style to your child theme: .add_to_cart_inline > a{margin-left:10px;}
